# Javascript- Regular expression

Tags: javascript

```
 sampleText='6501-*-5-[*]'
```

Expected output

```
 result='6501-%-5-[*]'
```

I have to replace * by % and leave [*] as it is. There might be multiple occurance of both. 
How can we i do it in javascript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sampleText = sampleText.replace(/\*/g, function(match, offset){
    if(offset > 0) {
        if(sampleText[offset - 1] == '[' && sampleText[offset + 1] == ']'){
            return match;
        }
    }
    return '%';
});
```

fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JwwwV/1/)

Comment: one more thing  SampleText=*r[*]d[a*bacd]                                                                     ResultText=%r*da*bacd  i.e. anything inside square brackets is to be ignored... How can i do this.. Any direction on this...?

Comment: @user714537 It's pretty simple but i left it to you as an exercise :)

Comment: I'm able to ignore the characters within square bracket. But ' * ' outside the bracket is not getting replaced with '%'. I have tried this..    sampleText.replace(/[[]^A-Za-z\d_*]+/g, '')

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String.replace() method. Docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

For example:

```
text = '6501-*-5-[*]';
text = text.replace('-*-','-%-');
console.log(text); // 6501-%-5-[*]
```

Comment: replace **first** -*- with -%- is not his requirement